# Pyspark : How to replace value each row with value in array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I will change number in column date with value in monthList array.

**monthList array**

`monthList = ["None","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]`

**pyspark code**

```
d = df.select(col('InvoiceDate'),col('TotalSales')/1000000).groupBy(month('InvoiceDate')).sum()
d = d.select(col('month(InvoiceDate)').alias('date'),col('sum((TotalSales / 1000000))').alias('value')).orderBy('date')
d = d.select(col('date'),round(col('value'),2).alias('value'))
d.show()
```

**result**

```
+----+-----+
|date|value|
+----+-----+
|   1|19.75|
|   2|15.51|
|   3|20.66|
+----+-----+
```

I will try this but it not working. It's error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'`

```
d.date = d.select('date').apply(lambda x: monthList[x])
```

Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this alternative-

```scala
df1.selectExpr(
      s"element_at(array('None','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'), date) as date",
      "value"
    ).show(false)

    /**
      * +----+-----+
      * |date|value|
      * +----+-----+
      * |None|19.75|
      * |Jan |15.51|
      * |Feb |20.66|
      * +----+-----+
      */
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach can be creating dataframe(`date_lookup`) upfront with the `monthlist`. This df can be `broadcasted` for performance. Then you can perform left join with actual df.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

 spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('practice')\
.getOrCreate()

 sc= spark.sparkContext

monthList = ["None","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

lookup_list = []

for i in range(len(monthList)):
   lookup_list.append((i,monthList[i]))


date_lookup = sc.parallelize(lookup_list).toDF(["date_num", "date_label"])

date_lookup.show()

 +--------+----------+
 |date_num|date_label|
 +--------+----------+
 |       0|      None|
 |       1|       Jan|
 |       2|       Feb|
 |       3|       Mar|
 |       4|       Apr|
 |       5|       May|
 |       6|       Jun|
 |       7|       Jul|
 |       8|       Aug|
 |       9|       Sep|
 |      10|       Oct|
 |      11|       Nov|
 |      12|       Dec|
 +--------+----------+

 df= sc.parallelize([
 (1,19.75), (2,15.51)]).toDF(["date", "value"])

 +----+-----+
 |date|value|
 +----+-----+
 |   1|19.75|
 |   2|15.51|
 +----+-----+

 df1  = df.join(F.broadcast(date_lookup),df.date==date_lookup.date_num, how='left').select('date_label','value')

 df1.show()

 +----------+-----+
 |date_label|value|
 +----------+-----+
 |       Jan|19.75|
 |       Feb|15.51|
 +----------+-----+
```